# How to make multi-dimensional table from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I  have a database table named:expenditures(given image no.1) that stores some official expenditures.
[image]

Explanation: Here sub_head_id is foreign key that has relation with another table name:subheads (given image no.2) that stores sub_head name. ex_date stores expenditure date.
[image]

What i want is: i want to get month wise yearly report of those expenditures.
Desired result:
[image]

How can make this in a php.blade file as i am using laravel 5.4?
Anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `SELECT` statements to generate columns for months, e.g.:

```
SELECT s.head_id, s.acc_sub_head,
 (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM exenditures WHERE sub_head_id = s.head_id AND ex_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-31') AS 'January 2017',
 (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM exenditures WHERE sub_head_id = s.head_id AND ex_date BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-28') AS 'February 2017',
 (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM exenditures WHERE sub_head_id = s.head_id AND ex_date BETWEEN '2017-03-01' AND '2017-03-31') AS 'March 2017',
 (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM exenditures WHERE sub_head_id = s.head_id AND ex_date BETWEEN '2017-04-01' AND '2017-04-30') AS 'April 2017',
FROM exenditures e JOIN subheads s ON e.sub_head_id = s.head_id
GROUP BY s.head_id, s.acc_sub_head;
```

You can add more `SELECT` queries for more months.

Comment: Great! i found the clue from you! @Metha